# How build NDVI based on multi-bands on different files (one band - one file) in geoserver?

Tags: geoserver, ndvi, multi-band, band

I am using a geoserver. I have several bands (b1, b2, b3..etc) I need to build NDVI based on them, for this I need to have access to each of the bands, but since they are in separate files, when I load data like GEOTIFF, I only see one layer (b1 or b3 or b4). How can I upload 10 land files one at a time and use them? I have all the files, just specifically the GEOTIFF repository allows you to download only 1 file, that is, 1 band in my case.

Comment: I would use a GIS like QGIS for this operation and then load the resulting GeoTIFF(s) into GeoServer. That way you only need to make the calculation once rather that ecer time the user views the map

Comment: @IanTurton How exactly would you use? What needs to be done in qgis?